# Monogame and Android, rendering is shifted up. All KitKat devices

Tags: android, xamarin.android, samsung-mobile, android-4.4-kitkat, monogame

Here's some simple source code I used to reproduce the error in a controlled environment:  https://bitbucket.org/nykular_sinha/shiftedgraphics/src

On a couple devices, the game renders above where it should. Here's a screenshot of what should be the entire map in the center, but is the bottom three rows at the top [image: screenshot]
The first time the game loads, it displays fine. If I exit out, and go back in, everything is shifted off. If I don't run the app long enough, the problem will go away for one run. I guess whatever caching is done is causing problems. To top it off, it won't occur as long as I have Visual Studio connected in debug mode.

I'm certain my drawing parameters are correct, since I've logged them to the console and they look fine, and the touch sensitive locations still work fine. Everything is just draw in the wrong place. Plus, it works on a Galaxy Nexus, Kindle Fire, and Galaxy Tab 2.

<strike>This has happened on a Galaxy S3 rooted with Android 4.4.3 and a Galaxy S5 with Android 4.4.2. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the SX series or with the newest builds of Android.</strike>
I've confirmed this happens on multiple KitKat devices, including the Galaxy S3, S5, and LG/Google's Nexus 5.

Steps to Reproduce:
1) Run app on phone.
2) Disconnect USB debugging
3) Exit app
4) Run app again

If the error doesn't happen immediately, exit and rerun a couple of times.  I've never had to do step 4 more than twice to reproduce the error.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?